# Is it good or bad practise to alter start dates in a database to the next occurrence of an event?

Tags: php, mysql, date, calendar, recurring

I am trying to create an event calendar which whilst initially quite small could turn out to be quite large. To that end, when trying to future proof it as much as possible, all events that occur in the past will be deleted from the database. However, is it bad practise to alter the start date of recurring events once they have happened to indicate when the next event will start? This makes it easier to perform search queries because theoretically no events will start more than say a week in the past, depending on how often the database is updated.

Is there a better way to do this?

My current intention is to have a table listing the event details along with a column for whether it is a yearly, monthly, weekly or daily recurrence. When somebody then searches for events between 2 dates, I simply look at each row and check if (EVENT START <= SEARCH FINISH && EVENT FINISH >= SEARCH START). This then gets all the possible events, and the recurring ones then need to be checked to see if they occur during the time period given. This is where I come a little unstuck, as to how to achieve this specifically. My thoughts are as follows:

Yearly: if EVENT START + 1 YEAR <= SEARCH FINISH || EVENT FINISH + 1 Year >= SEARCH START; repeat for +2 YEARS etc until EVENT START + NO YEARS > SEARCH FINISH.

Monthly: As above but + 1 month each time.

Weekly: As above but EVENT START and EVENT FINISH will be plus 7 DAYS BETWEEN RECURRENCE each iteration until EVENT START + 7 DAYS REPEATED > SEARCH FINISH.

Daily: As above but NO OF DAYS DIFFERENCE instead of 7 days for a week. This could be used to specify things like every 14 days (fortnight), every 10 days. Even every week could use this method.

However, when I think about the query that would have to be built to achieve this, I cannot help think that it will be very cumbersome and probably slow. Is there a better way to achieve the results I want? I have still not found a way to do things like occurs on the first Monday of a month or the last Friday of a month, or the second Saturday of April each year. Are these latter options even possible?

-- Edit: added below:

It might help a bit if I explain a bit more about what I am creating. That way guidance can be given with respect to that.

I am creating a website which allows organisations to add events, whether they are a one-off or recurring (daily, weekly, monthly, first Tuesday of a month etc.). The user of the site will then be able to search for events within a chosen distance (arbitrary 10, 25, 50, 100miles, all of country) on a set date or between 2 given dates which could be from 1 day apart up to a couple of years apart (obviously events that far into the future will be minimal or non-existant depending on the dates used).

The EVENTS table itself currently holds a lot of information about the event, such as location, cost, age group etc. Would it be better to have this in a separate table which is looked up once it has been determined if the event is within the specified search parameters? Clearly not all of this information is needed until the detailed page view, maybe just a name,  location, cost and brief description.

I appreciate there are many ways to skin a cat but I am unsure how to skin this one. The biggest thing I am struggling with is how to structure my data so that a query will know if the recursion is within the specified date. Also, given that the mathematics to calculate distance between 2 lat/longs is relatively complex, I need to be able to build this calculation into my query, otherwise I will be doing the calculation in PHP anyway. Granted, there will be less results to process this way, but it still needs to be done.

Any further advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating events for each recurrence is unnecessary. It is much better to store the details that define how the event recurs.  This question has been answered many times on SO.

One way to do this is to use a structure like this -

```
tblEvent
--------
id
name
description
date

tblEventRecurring
-----------------
event_id
date_part
end_date
```

Then you could use a query like this to retrieve events -

```
SELECT *
FROM `tblEvent`
LEFT JOIN `tblEventRecurring`
    ON `tblEvent`.`id` = `tblEventRecurring`.`event_id`
WHERE (`tblEvent`.`date` = CURRENT_DATE AND `tblEventRecurring`.`event_id` IS NULL)
OR (
    CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN `tblEvent`.`date` AND `tblEventRecurring`.`end_date`
    AND (
        (`tblEventRecurring`.`date_part` = 'D') OR
        (`tblEventRecurring`.`date_part` = 'W' AND DAYOFWEEK(`tblEvent`.`date`) = DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) OR
        (`tblEventRecurring`.`date_part` = 'M' AND DAYOFMONTH(`tblEvent`.`date`) = DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE))
    )
)
```

**UPDATE** Added the following example of returning events for a given date range.

When returning dates for a given date range you can join the above query to a table representing the date range -

```
SET @start_date = '2012-03-26';
SET @end_date = '2012-04-01';

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT @start_date + INTERVAL num DAY AS `date`
    FROM dummy
    WHERE num < (DATEDIFF(@end_date, @start_date) + 1)
) AS `date_list`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `tblEvent`.`id`, `tblEvent`.`date`, `tblEvent`.`name`, `tblEventRecurring`.`date_part`, `tblEventRecurring`.`end_date`
    FROM `tblEvent`
    LEFT JOIN `tblEventRecurring`
        ON `tblEvent`.`id` = `tblEventRecurring`.`event_id`
    WHERE `tblEvent`.`date` BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
    OR (`tblEvent`.`date` < @end_date AND `tblEventRecurring`.`end_date` > @start_date)
) AS `events`
    ON `events`.`date` = `date_list`.`date`
    OR (
        `date_list`.`date` BETWEEN `events`.`date` AND `events`.`end_date`
        AND (
            (`events`.`date_part` = 'D') OR
            (`events`.`date_part` = 'W' AND DAYOFWEEK(`events`.`date`) = DAYOFWEEK(`date_list`.`date`)) OR
            (`events`.`date_part` = 'M' AND DAYOFMONTH(`events`.`date`) = DAYOFMONTH(`date_list`.`date`))
        )
    )
WHERE `date_list`.`date` BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
ORDER BY `date_list`.`date`;
```

You can replace the SQL variables with PHP vars if you would prefer.  To display days without any events you can change the `INNER JOIN` between the two derived tables, `date_list` and `events`, to a LEFT JOIN.

The table `dummy` consists of a single column with numbers from 0 to whatever you anticipate needing. This example creates the dummy table with enough data to cover one month. You could easily populate it using an `INSERT... SELECT...` on the AI PK of another table -

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy` (
    `num` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO `dummy` VALUES
    (00), (01), (02), (03), (04), (05), (06), (07), (08), (09),
    (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
    (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29),
    (30), (31);
```

Comment: Having looked at this example, I understand how it works. If a user is searching between 2 dates, I could construct the SQL statement using PHP, iterating through each date and replacing CURRENT_DATE with the explicit date and concatenate them all to give me one query string. I am worried that this could potentially result in massive SQL query strings, is this a problem? They are dynamically created so I can't see it being too much of an issue. Is there a better way to achieve the same result? I started reading my shiny new SQL book today so hopefully I'll be a bit more enlightened soon!

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of returning the events for a given date range.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the query is selecting every date within range and joining to that only events that have matching dates to those in the date range. However, I then get stuck as to what the OR relates to. To me it looks like SLECT * FROM date_list INNER JOIN events OR confused WHERE that date is between my start and end dates. Have I missed something here?

Comment: The OR deals with the recurring events. The D, W, M represent Daily, Weekly and Monthly recurrence. If the day we are checking is between events.date (start date) and events.end_date then we need to see if it matches the type of recurrence for the event. If daily we do not need to check anything else. If weekly we need to check that the DAYOFWEEK() is the same. If monthly then we need to check that DAYOFMONTH() is the same. Are you able to understand it now?

Answer (score 1):

Break it up
Have one table for vents that haven't happened yet with a reccurring event ID. So you can just poke one offs in there with recurring veent id of null. Get rid /archive past ones etc.

Have another for the data about recurring events.

When an event marked as recurring happens, go back to recurring table, check to see if it's enabled (you might want to add a range to them ie do this every wek for three months), and if all is okay, add a new record for the next time it occurs.

One way to do it anyway, and it gets rid of the problem of using event start for two different things which is why your code is getting complicated.

If you want future jobs from this. ie everything needed to do in the next month.

The  it would be a union query. One to get all teh "current jobs", unioned with one to get all the jobs that will recur in the next month.

Can't stress this enough, get the data design right the code "just happens". If you data is messed up as in one field "start date" serving two different needs, then every time you go near it, you have to deal with that dual use. Forget it once and you get anything from a painful mess to a disaster.

Adding a Recurring_Start_Date column would be better than your current plan, wouldn't it. You wouldn't be asking this question, beacseu your data would fit your needs.

Comment: I've considered something along those lines but it doesn't really work for what I want to achieve. If I query the database for all possible events occurring within the specified date range and return those, is it good or bad programming practise to then process and filter the results in my php class to only get the ones that are relevant? This seems much easier to me given the complexity of determining if a recurring event is within the date range required.

Comment: Bad. Getting data you don't need is expensive. Edited for rest

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'll be searching through events much more frequently than you will be creating new ones.  During event creation, I would create records for each occurrence of the event up to so reasonable amount of time (maybe for the next year or two).

It would also make things like "The third thursday of each month" a little easier.  If you tried to do any of the calculations in a query it would be difficult and probably slow.